# $ \epsilon \frac{d^2 u}{d x^2}+ \frac{du}{dx} -a -2bx=0$ ; 0<x<1 where u(0)=0,and u(1)=1. Find the approximate solutio

Tags: perturbation-theory

Consider the problem
\begin{equation} \tag{*} \label{equ:given eqn} \epsilon \frac{d^2 u}{d x^2}+ \frac{du}{dx} -a -2bx=0 ; \ \ \ 0<x<1 
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation} \tag{**} \label{equ:given_condition_1}
 u(0)=0,  ~\text{ and }~   u(1)=1 
\end{equation}
Find the approximate solution

#### Step 1: Outer Solution

Consider
$$
u(x) \sim u_0(x) + \epsilon u_1(x)+ ... 
$$
Then we obtain
$$\epsilon (u''_0(x) + \epsilon u''_1(x)+ ...) +  (u'_0(x) + \epsilon u'_1(x)+ ...)=a+2bx $$

The $O(1)$ equation is therefore
$$
 u'_0(x)=a+2bx  \tag1
$$
Using the separation of variables we get the general solution
\begin{equation} \tag2 \label{equ:general_outer_solution}
 u_0(x)= ax+bx^2+C 
\end{equation}
Where $C$ is any arbitrary constant.

Looking at the solution, we have a dilemma because there is only one arbitrary constant but there are two boundary conditions. We have no idea which boundary condition, if any, we should require $u_0(x)$ to satisfy.

#### Step 2: Boundary Layer

Let us assume that there is a boundary layer at $x=0$, we introduce a boundary layer co-ordinate as
\begin{equation}
 \bar{x}= \frac{x}{\epsilon^\alpha} \tag3
\end{equation}
where $\alpha>0$. From the change of variables and the chain rule, we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}&=\frac{1}{\epsilon^\alpha} \frac{d}{d \bar{x}}\tag{4a}
\\
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}&=\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2\alpha}} \frac{d^2}{d^2 \bar{x}}\tag{4b}
\end{align}
If we let $U(\bar{x})$ denote the solution of the problem when using the boundary layer co-ordinate, then \eqref{equ:given eqn} transforms to
\begin{equation} \tag5 \label{equ:boundary_layer}
 \epsilon^{1-2\alpha} \frac{d^2U}{d\bar{x}^2}+\epsilon^{-\alpha} \frac{dU}{d\bar{x}}=a+2b {\epsilon}^\alpha \bar{x}
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}\tag6
 U(0)=0
\end{equation}
The boundary condition $x=0$ is included here because the boundary layer is at the left end of the interval.

The appropriate expansion for the boundary-layer solution is now
\begin{equation}\tag7
 U(\bar{x}) \sim U_0(\bar{x})+ \epsilon^\gamma U_1(\bar{x})+...
\end{equation}
where $\gamma >0$. In this expansion $\bar{x}$ is held fixed as $\epsilon$ goes to zero. Then
\begin{equation}\tag8
\epsilon^{1-2\alpha} (  U''_0(\bar{x})+ ... )+ \epsilon^{-\alpha} (  U'_0(\bar{x}+ ...)=
a+2b {\epsilon}^\alpha \bar{x}
\end{equation}
Now I want to find the value of $\alpha$ by balancing. By balancing First term with the second term I get $\alpha =1$ and by balancing first term with last term we get $\alpha=1/3$. But I am not sure.

Comment: If $\alpha=1$ then in the last equation in the question you have terms that are $O(\epsilon^{-1})$, $O(\epsilon^{-1})$, $O(1)$ and $O(\epsilon)$, so the largest terms (the $O(\epsilon^{-1})$ terms) do balance. So this is a valid dominant balance. If $\alpha=1/3$ then the terms are $O(\epsilon^{1/3})$, $O(\epsilon^{-1/3})$, $O(1)$ and $O(\epsilon^{1/3})$, and now the largest term $O(\epsilon^{-1/3})$ can't balance with any other term. So it is not a dominant balance. So in this case, you need to pick $\alpha=1$.

Comment: Thank you. I already did this.

Comment: Then what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

I am puzzled as to why the problem asks for an "approximation" when it is very easy to find the exact solution!  Because this is a linear equation it is not necessary to use perturbation methods.

The equation is $\epsilon \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+ \frac{du}{dx}- a= 2bx
$.  The associated homogeneous equation is $\epsilon \frac{d^2y}{d^2x}+ \frac{du}{dx}- a$ which has characteristic equation $\epsilon r^2+ r- a= 0$, solutions $r= \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+ 4a\epsilon}}{2\epsilon}$.

We would then seek a solution to the entire equation of the form $u= Ax+ B$.  $\frac{du}{dx}= A$ and $\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}= 0$ so the equation reduces to $A- a= Ax+ B$.  So A= 0 and B= -a.  $u= -a$ satisfies the equation so the general solution is $u(x)= e^{-x/2\epsilon}\left(C_1e^{\frac{\sqrt{1+ 4a\epsilon}}{2\epsilon}t}+ C_2e^{\frac{\sqrt{1+ 4a\epsilon}}{2\epsilon}t}\right)- a$.

Comment: This problem comes from the perturbation and it said to find approximate solution upto O(epsilon).

Comment: @user247327 I think it's clear this is an introductory example to motivate/introduce perturbation theory so being able to compare with a true solution may be helpful.

Comment: Note that $a$ is a constant term, not a linear term. The equation is really $ϵu''+u'=a+2b\implies ϵu'+u=ax+bx^2+c$, which makes the exact solution even simpler.